# Trying to include setasign/fpdf via composer

Tags: php, laravel-5, composer-php, fpdf, fpdi

I'm trying to include fpdf and fpdi via installing `setasign/fpdi-fpdf` through composer but I can't seem to get fpdf or fpdi loaded. The error I get is `Class 'setasign\fpdf\FPDF' not found`.

```
use \setasign\fpdf\FPDF as FPDF;

//inside controller function
fpdf::AddPage();
fpdf::SetFont('Courier', 'B', 18);
fpdf::Cell(50, 25, 'Hello World!');
fpdf::Output();
```

Maybe I should be adding something to the `config/app.php` file in order to load the classes?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

FPDF is not namespaced. [The package](https://packagist.org/packages/setasign/fpdf) is a clone of the original release with an additional composer.json file. Nothing more.

Just use `\FPDF` if you want to use the FPDF class.

The latest FPDI release is namespaced: `\setasign\Fpdi\Fpdi`

Additionally you should/cannot call the methods static.